# Dans quel ordre place-t-on les compléments d'objet du verbe « contribuer » ?

Tags: syntaxe

Jean paie un tiers des frais médicaux et la source de cette contribution-là sont ses épargnes.

Laquelle des six phrases suivantes communique cela correctement ?

1. Jean a contribué aux frais médicaux de ses épargnes pour un tiers.
2. Jean a contribué de ses épargnes aux frais médicaux pour un tiers.
3. Jean a contribué pour un tiers aux frais médicaux de ses épargnes.
4. Jean a contribué aux frais médicaux pour un tiers de ses épargnes.
5. Jean a contribué de ses épargnes pour un tiers aux frais médicaux.
6. Jean a contribué pour un tiers de ses épargnes aux frais médicaux.

Answer (score 3):

« Contribuer de qqch » où *qqch* désigne ce que l'on contribue est assez rare en français moderne. Je pense que c'est une forme quasi-figée où l'on ne peut pas couper « contribuer de ». Quand je lis, par exemple, (1) « Jean a contribué aux frais médicaux de ses épargnes pour un tiers », la grammaire ne me laisse qu'une seule interprétation possible : « les frais médicaux de ses épargnes » est un groupe nominal (mais après la phrase n'a pas de sens). Ceci exclut les phrases (1), (3), (4) et (6).

L'expression « pour un tiers » est correcte, mais elle pose un problème parce qu'elle est ambiguë : il peut s'agir soit de la fraction 1/3, soit du nom *tiers* dans le sens « une autre personne ». On peut éviter l'ambiguïté en utilisant « au tiers » qui a le même sens. Ce problème ne se poserait pas avec une autre fraction (« pour deux tiers » = « aux deux tiers », « pour un quart » = « au quart », …). Cas particulier : 1/2 ne peut se dire que « pour moitié », pas « *<s>à une moitié</s> ».

Par ailleurs il y a une ambiguïté sur ce que la fraction 1/3 représente dans les deux phrases restantes :

> (2) Jean a contribué de ses épargnes aux frais médicaux pour un tiers.

Toute la contribution de Jean vient de ses épargnes. Il y a ambiguïté entre :

- La contribution de Jean vaut 1/3 des frais médicaux.
- 1/3 de sa contribution est pour les frais médicaux, et le reste est pour d'autres usages.

> (5) Jean a contribué de ses épargnes pour un tiers aux frais médicaux.

Il y a ambiguïté entre :

- 1/3 de la contribution de Jean vient de ses épargnes, et Jean a obtenu les 2/3 restants par une autre méthode (emprunt, donation, vente, …). La contribution est entièrement pour les frais médicaux.
- Toute la contribution de Jean vient de ses épargnes. La contribution de Jean vaut 1/3 des frais médicaux.
- Toute la contribution de Jean vient de ses épargnes. 1/3 de sa contribution est pour les frais médicaux, et le reste est pour d'autres usages.

La manière la plus naturelle de tourner la phrase, qui évite toute ambiguïté sur quoi porte la fraction 1/3, est de parler d'« un tiers des frais médicaux ».

> Jean a contribué de son épargne au tiers des frais médicaux.

On peut utiliser une autre préposition que *de* pour l'origine de la contribution. Dans ce cas il n'y a pas de contrainte sur l'ordre entre les deux compléments.

> Jean a contribué par son épargne au tiers des frais médicaux.
> Jean a contribué au tiers des frais médicaux par son épargne.
> Jean a contribué grâce à son épargne au tiers des frais médicaux.
> Jean a contribué au tiers des frais médicaux grâce à son épargne.

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord sur la "forme figée".

Answer (score 2):

Toutes les phrases proposées sont plus ou moins bancales. Aucune n'est vraiment claire et ne rend l'idée exprimée. Voici ce que j'écrirais :

> Jean a financé un tiers de ses frais médicaux avec ses économies.

S'il faut vraiment conserver au maximum les tournures utilisées :

> Les frais médicaux, Jean y a contribué pour un tiers et de ses épargnes.

Comment: Bien sûr que l'idée peut être exprimée de manière moins ambiguë, notamment par le biais de l'utilisation d'un verbe autre que _contribuer_. Toutefois, la question, en l'occurence celle de savoir l'ordre dans lequel les compléments d'objet doivent être placés, restera alors entière.

Comment: Aucun ordre n'est acceptable avec les tournures choisies. Une accumulation de propositions potentiellement ambiguës ne s'auto-corrige pas.  Aux frais médicaux de qui? Pour quel tiers? Les épargnes de qui?

Comment: @peanutjelly Votre postulat est faux. *Contribuer* prend 1 seul complément obligatoire (il projette 1 seul rôle thêta, l'objet de la contribution), non plusieurs. D'éventuels autres compléments, facultatifs pour leur part et indépendants de la valence du verbe, sont des adjoints n'ayant pas besoin d'autorisation liée à la structure événementielle du prédicat, et exprimant par ex. le moyen, la source. (1/2)

Comment: L'ordre naturel est de placer l'argument juste après le verbe: on *contribue à quelque chose (avec/grâce à...)*; maintenant, une montée est toujours possible, mais dans ce cas, cela produit un effet stylistique d'emphase de ce "COI" retardé. (2/2)

Comment: @peanutjelly Votre postulat est faux. *Contribuer* prend 1 seul complément obligatoire (il projette 1 seul rôle thêta, l'objet de la contribution), non plusieurs. D'éventuels autres compléments, facultatifs pour leur part et indépendants de la valence du verbe, sont des adjoints n'ayant pas besoin d'autorisation liée à la structure événementielle du prédicat, et exprimant par ex. le moyen, la source. Un diagnostic facile, on peut les détacher: *de mes propres deniers, j'ai contribué à son rétablissement*. (1/2)

Answer (score -1):

« Contribuer de qqc » dans le sens de « tirer de qqc » n'existe pas, ce qui force l'utilisation de constructions plus compliquées.

> 1. Jean a contribué aux frais médicaux de ses épargnes pour un tiers.

*Jean a payé les frais médicaux au moyen de ses épargnes, le paiement s'élevant à un tiers des frais totaux.*

> 2. Jean a contribué de ses épargnes aux frais médicaux pour un tiers.

*Jean a tiré de ses épargnes une somme pour les frais médicaux, somme qui correspond à un tiers des frais.*

> 3. Jean a contribué pour un tiers aux frais médicaux de ses épargnes.

*Jean a contribué pour un tiers des frais médicaux en se servant de ses épargnes.*

> 4. Jean a contribué aux frais médicaux pour un tiers de ses épargnes.

*Jean a contribué aux frais médicaux pour un tiers et il a réglé ce tiers au moyen de ses épargnes.*

> 5. Jean a contribué de ses épargnes pour un tiers aux frais médicaux.

*Jean a tiré de ses épargnes une somme d'un montant égal au tiers des frais médicaux, somme qui était sa contribution aux frais totaux.*

> 6. Jean a contribué pour un tiers de ses épargnes aux frais médicaux.

Il semble qu'il n'y aurait pas de construction qui préserve l'ordre dans le cas de cette dernière phrase.

## Addition suite au commentaires de user peanutjelly

Il existe deux définitions pour ce verbe ; on les trouve au TLFi.

> **A.− Aider, participer (avec d'autres) à la réalisation d'un projet, d'une entreprise; avoir une part, plus ou moins importante, dans la production d'un résultat, d'un état.** Cf. collaborer, concourir, coopérer.
>
> 1. **Contribuer à + subst**. désignant une action, un état ou un changement d'état.
> 2. **Contribuer à + inf**. exprimant une action, le passage d'un état à un autre.Contribuer à accroître, à développer, à restaurer qqc.; (plus rarement) contribuer à détruire, à diminuer qqc.

> **B.− Spéc. Payer sa part d'une dépense, d'une charge commune**. La qualité de citoyens oblige seulement à contribuer à la dépense commune de l'État, suivant ses facultés (Robesp., Discours,Marc argent, t. 7, 1791, p. 162).
>
> - Il [l'État] a contribué de ses deniers à la restauration d'édifices qui ne lui appartiennent pas (Barrès, Cahiers,t. 9, 1912, p. 376)

D'après ce que j'ai pu constater pour l'instant il me semble que ce « de » exprime la manière ou plutôt la nature de la contribution mais pas l'origine ; on trouve par exemple aussi « contribuer de ses soins  », « de sa part  », « de son sang », « de sa sueur », « de sa personne », …

Ceci devient plus clair dans la définition d'un dictionnaire ancien de chez Bescherelle.

> [Dictionnaire national, ou, Dictionnaire universel de la langue française - 1863](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dictionnaire_national_ou_Dictionnaire_un/xcs5AQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22contribu%C3%A9+de%22&pg=PA769&printsec=frontcover)
>
> Aider de quelque manière que ce soit, à l'exécution, au succès d'un dessein, d'une entreprise

On retrouve  la définition « **A** » du TLFi, avec ceci en plus qu'il est mentionné qu'une manière peut être envisagée. Il est vrai que l'exemple dans la définition « **B** » du TLFi est un exemple d'usage avec l'expression  « de ses deniers » : cependant, l'idée est celle de la définition « **A** » ; elle domine largement dans le français des 17ième, 18ième et 19ième siècles, mais dans le français du siècle dernier et dans celui du présent siècle on ne trouve pas de cas : « de » est utilisé pour introduire une manière réelle ; ceci se vérifie dans les quelque 300 ouvrages de cette page de 100 ([a contribué](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22contribu%C3%A9%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)) et les trois suivantes. Dans le glissement de « **A** » vers « **B** » une confusion des deux nuances aurait persisté quelques temps. On trouve « a contribué de son argent » jusqu'en 1922 seulement et avant cette date on ne le trouve presque pas. ([a contribué de son argent](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20contribu%C3%A9%20de%20son%20argent%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)) ;

Le sens qui devrait être donné à ce « de » serait le suivant.

**contribuer de qqc** : contribuer par l'apport de

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141688/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-dans-quel-ordre-place-t-on-les-complements-dobjet-d).